# How to add group by clauses based on different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database like this :
The first column is the name of the city. A, B and C are the columns with binary data 1 for yes and 0 for no.

(Database Name - D1)

```
City         A              B              C
----    ------------    -----------    --------
Boston      1               1              1
Chicago     1               0              0
Boston      1               0              0
Boston      1               1              0
Chicago     1               1              0
```

I want to group these cities and have columns giving me counts of 1's in column A, B, and C like below

```
City       Count A        Count B       Count C     
----    ------------    -----------    --------
Boston      3               2              1
Chicago     2               1              0
```

The following code will give me the first column. Is there a way I can get all the three columns using a single query by using group by?

```
SELECT City, COUNT(A) as Count A
FROM D1
GROUP BY City
Where City.A = 1
```

Comment: If all you have are `1` and `0` then `SUM()` will give you the count.

Comment: Is `A`, `B`, and `C`, (etc?) an `int`, or is it a `bit`?

Comment: @Larnu It is stored as int but functions like bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use count (to return a 0 if null values are present) then you can use a case statement within the count function to achieve this.

```
declare @city table (
    City char(15),
    A int,
    B int,
    C int
);
insert @city (City, A, B, C)
values
('Boston', 1, 1, 1),
('Chicago', 1, 0, 0),
('Boston', 1, 0, 0),
('Boston', 1, 1, 0),
('Chicago', 1, 1, 0);

select * from @city;

select City,
       count(case when A>0 then 1 end) as CountA,
       count(case when B>0 then 1 end) as CountB,
       count(case when C>0 then 1 end) as CountC
from @city group by City;
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Basically, instead of counting you can use `sum()`.

```
SELECT City
    ,Sum(A) as CountA
    ,Sum(B) as CountB
    ,Sum(C) as CountC
FROM D1
GROUP BY City
```

If columns `A, B, C` are of `bit` data type you need to cast them to a data type that allows aggregations i.e. `integer`.

```
SELECT City
    ,Sum(cast(A as int)) as CountA
    ,Sum(cast(B as int)) as CountB
    ,Sum(cast(C as int)) as CountC
FROM D1
GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `SUM` Function, like this:

```
SELECT City
    ,Sum(A) as sum_A
    ,Sum(B) as sum_B
    ,Sum(C) as sum_C
FROM D1
GROUP BY City
```

Please, check the official docs: [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why do you say they should use HAVING and have a link to the documentation but that clause isn't in your code? The query you posted works but the explanation makes no sense here.